# TDD/BDD framework for use with Django?

Tags: python, testing

I'm trying to decide which approach to take to testing a Django app I'm writing. I've seen Cucumber and that put me onto lettuce (URL is lettuce.it) and [pycurracy](http://github.com/heynemann/pyccuracy). I like the look of these frameworks since hopefully non-technical people will be able to write definitions.

I want to be able to:

- run functional tests integrated with Django, so sometimes inspecting models,
- test behaviours via a web browser - pycurracy seems to make this easier since there are already Selenium bindings. But Selenium is slow, so I'd be happier using a headless, ideally Javascript-capable browser for testing.

It seems like Lettuce can do the first easily, but the second will require me to build a library of steps for actions like "I click button x", etc. Conversely, I can't see any specific mention of Django and Pycurracy, although it can handle the second point.

Lettuce has a lower version number, but that doesn't mean it's inferior.

Has anyone used either or both of these? Any advice?

How do these work out when you have a reasonably large/complex project?

Comment: I know Cucumber can test Python code, but I want a Python solution to keep things easier for colleagues.

Comment: Please do not comment on your own question.  Just edit your question.

Comment: What's wrong with Django's own testing framework?  It totally works and does much of what you want.

Answer (score 5):

It seems that at the moment, [Lettuce](http://lettuce.it/) can do a lot of what you want, and it has [built-in support for Django](http://lettuce.it/recipes/django-lxml.html).

But why not use a combination of the tools you like?

Answer (score 0):

[Aloe-django](https://aloe.readthedocs.org/projects/aloe-django/en/latest/) is a great tool and it plays well with django 1.8 its actually started as a fork from lettuce

from their docs:

> Aloe-Django originally started life as part of the Python BDD tool
>   Lettuce. Like so many succulents, it grew into so much more than that.

I use it in my django 1.7 soon to be 1.8 project and it's great